# XPath Query to check if td has certain children (C# + Selenium)

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

I hope someone can help me out, I am stuck with an XPath expression. I have the following HTML extracted from a a tennismatch with C# and Selenium:

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="g_2_CvUnLIxC" class="tr-first stage-live" style="cursor: pointer;" title="">
    <td rowspan="2" class="cell_ib icons left"><span class="icons left"><span class="tomyg icon0"></span></span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="cell_ad time  time-playing" title="Click for match detail!">21:00</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="cell_aa timer  playing" title="Click for match detail!"><span>Set 3</span></td>
    <td class="cell_xh serve-home" title="">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="cell_ab team-home" title="Click for match detail!"><span class="padl">Barrientos N. (Col)</span></td>
    <td class="cell_sc score-home  bold playing">1</td>
    <td class="cell_sd part-bottom" title="Click for match detail!">7</td>
    <td class="cell_se part-bottom" title="Click for match detail!">2</td>
    <td class="cell_sf part-bottom">4</td>
    <td class="cell_sg part-bottom">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="cell_sh part-bottom">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="cell_sp part-bottom highlight-highlighted">15</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="cell_ia icons"><span class="icons"><span class="tv icon1"></span></span></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="cell_oq comparison"><span class="icons"><span class="clive icon0"></span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="x_2_CvUnLIxC" class="tr-first stage-live" style="cursor: pointer;" title="">
    <td class="cell_xa serve-away" title=""><span class="icons" title=""><span class="tennis-serve" title="Serving player"></span></span></td>
    <td class="cell_ac team-away" title="Click for match detail!"><span class="padl">Lapentti G. (Ecu)</span></td>
    <td class="cell_ta score-away  bold playing" title="Click for match detail!">1</td>
    <td class="cell_tb part-top">5</td>
    <td class="cell_tc part-top">6</td>
    <td class="cell_td part-top">5</td>
    <td class="cell_te part-top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="cell_tf part-top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="cell_to part-top highlight-highlighted" title="Click for match detail!">30</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Out of this I want to extract which player is currently serving, which is displayed by a ball symbol that is shown with the following span-tag inside a td-tag:

```
<span class="icons" title=""><span class="tennis-serve" title="Serving player"></span></span>
```

This is either set in serve-home or in serve-away:

```
<td class="cell_xh serve-home" title="">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="cell_xa serve-away" title=""><span class="icons" title=""><span class="tennis-serve" title="Serving player"></span></span></td>
```

What I want is something like the following pseudo code resembles:

```
IWebElement id = driver.FindElement(union ((By.Id(id1),By.Id(id2)); 
IWebElement serve = id.FindElement(By.XPath("td that contains <span class="icons" title=""><span class="tennis-serve" title="Serving player"></span></span> 

String serv

er = serve.getAttribut("class"); //contains then serve-home or serve-away

Find attached an example of what the website looks like, I want to find out if the ball is displayed at player 1 or 2:
[link](http://i44.tinypic.com/2e157v6.png)

Thank you in advance!
```

UPDATE1:

```
                IWebElement id1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id(txt_ID1.Text));
                IWebElement id2 = driver.FindElement(By.Id(txt_ID2.Text));

                ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement> elements = id1.FindElements(By.XPath("td[contains(@class,'serve')]"));
                ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement> elements2 = id2.FindElements(By.XPath("td[contains(@class,'serve')]"));

                foreach (IWebElement i in elements)
                {
                    if (i.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Contains("span"))
                        Console.WriteLine(i.GetAttribute("class"));
                }

                foreach (IWebElement i in elements2)
                {
                    if (i.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Contains("span"))
                        Console.WriteLine(i.GetAttribute("class"));
                }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not sure about C#, but here is how I would do it in Java:**

First, find all the `<td>` elements whose `class` attribute contains `"serve"`:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'serve')]"));
```

Then, find the first `<td>` element whose `innerHTML` attribute contains `"span"`:

```
for (WebElement element : elements)
    if (element.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("span"))
        return element.getAttribute("class");
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not as efficient as finding the elements in one statement, especially if you are using remote web driver

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xpath sequence `..` to get the parent of an identified element. Since the `td` you are looking for is a direct parent of the `<span class="tennis-serve" >`, it can be used like so:

```
//assuming this line correctly locates the table we are interested in
IWebElement id = driver.FindElement(union ((By.Id(id1),By.Id(id2)); 

//select all the td  elements containing the span with class="tennis-serve" in the above table
//the starting '.' looks for descendants of only the context node 'id' 
//if you want all serving players, use FindElements
var servers = id.FindElements(By.XPath(".//span[@class='tennis-serve']/..")); 

foreach(var s in servers)
{
    string servingBy = s.GetAttribute("class"); 
    Console.WriteLine(servingBy);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to change the "right" answer, it worked in a quick test with firebug, but in my actual code it always returns the serve of the first match in the table and not the selected. I got the solution of @barak manos to work with a minor change (removing the trailing // asthis seemed to make the query return to the main dom and not the already selected subset) - see UPDATE1. However I am still interested in learning how todo it with /.. operator.

Comment: Have updated the xpath to look for descendants of only the context node, which would be the `id`. Ensure that the correct table is selected by it's locator.